# Square root of a OpenCV's grey image using SSE

Tags: c++, opencv, sse, simd

given a grey cv::Mat (CV_8UC1) I want to return another cv::Mat containing the square root of the elements (CV_32FC1) and I want to do it with SSE2 intrinsics. I am having some problems with the conversion from 8-bit values to 32 float values to perform the square root. I would really appreciate any help. This is my code for now(it does not give correct values):

```
uchar *source = (uchar *)cv::alignPtr(image.data, 16);
float *sqDataPtr = cv::alignPtr((float *)Squared.data, 16); 
for (x = 0; x < (pixels - 16); x += 16) {
    __m128i a0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)(source + x));

    __m128i first8 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(a0, _mm_set1_epi8(0));
    __m128i last8 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(a0, _mm_set1_epi8(0));

    __m128i first4i = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(first8, _mm_set1_epi16(0));
    __m128i second4i = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(first8, _mm_set1_epi16(0));
    __m128 first4 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(first4i);
    __m128 second4 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(second4i);

    __m128i third4i = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(last8, _mm_set1_epi16(0));
    __m128i fourth4i = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(last8, _mm_set1_epi16(0));
    __m128 third4 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(third4i);
    __m128 fourth4 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(fourth4i);

    //  Store
    _mm_store_ps(sqDataPtr + x, _mm_sqrt_ps(first4));
    _mm_store_ps(sqDataPtr + x + 4, _mm_sqrt_ps(second4));
    _mm_store_ps(sqDataPtr + x + 8, _mm_sqrt_ps(third4));
    _mm_store_ps(sqDataPtr + x + 12, _mm_sqrt_ps(fourth4));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSE code looks OK, except that you're not processing the last 16 pixels:

```
for (x = 0; x < (pixels - 16); x += 16)
```

should be:

```
for (x = 0; x <= (pixels - 16); x += 16)
```

Note that if your image width is not a multiple of 16 then you will need to take care of any remaining pixels after the last full vector.

Also note that you are taking the `sqrt` of values in the range 0..255. It may be that you want normalised value in the range 0..1.0, in which case you'll want to scale the values accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I did not copy the remaining computations of the last pixels here for simplicity. This code, I do not know why is not resulting the correct values. Yes, I want the square root of values between 0...255. I do not know also if this is totally efficient.

Comment: OK - the loop still needs fixing though, for the sake of performance, as you are missing the opportunity to process one last full vector. As for the functionality, I suspect the problem may be somewhere other than in the SSE code - maybe try replacing the SSE code with a simple scalar loop to see if that works, or test the SSE loop in a separate test harness to verify it?

Comment: One more thing - I put your SSE code into a test harness and it passes (once the for loop upper bound is fixed).

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!. I will try to find why I do not have the same results!.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with SSE2, but I think that if performance is the issue you should use look-up table. Creation of look-up table is fast since you have only 256 possible values. Copy 4 bytes from look-up table into destination matrix should be a very efficient operation.

Comment: With a look up table you can only process one point per iteration, and it requires 2 loads and 1 store to process 1 input value. The SSE version processes 16 points per loop iteration, with only 1 load and 4 stores for 16 input values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but, yes, that is way slower.

Comment: even if you use OpenCV LUT function?

Comment: @Micka, afaik LUT function require same depth for input and output. In this case input is 8U and output is 32F.

Comment: @Paul R, from my experience filling the values of destination image with look-up table is as fast as performing memcpy operation on resulting image. How much faster than that it can be?

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov: there are various factors to be considered, e.g. CPU, cache size, image size, etc - it may be that for large images on a system with small caches or low memory bandwidth that even a LUT-based approach can saturate the available bandwidth. But for smaller images, or larger caches, there may be significant benefit from a more optimised approach using SIMD. As always it's a good idea to benchmark for your particular use case.

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov: FWIW I just benchmarked a LUT-based implementation versus the SSE implementation above, and on a Haswell CPU there is not much difference. So you're probably right - in some cases at least, a LUT-based approach is as good as a SIMD implementation for sqrt.